# 1996 Ford E350 (5.8L) Mass Air Flow Sensor - where is it?

Tags: ford, maf, econoline

I can't find the MAF sensor on my 96 Ford E350.  (Been googling for hours :))

In case a picture helps:

[image: Intake manifold]

Like I said, I've been looking for quite a while, and I can't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: If you got that far and didn't find a mass air flow sensor, have you considered the possibility of a MAP (manifold absolute pressure) sensor?

Comment: Ha - never thought of that! After a little research, it looks like I have one of those. I'll add an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the 1996 Ford E350 doesn't *have* a Mass Air Flow sensor - hence the trouble finding it :-)

Instead, it has a MAP (Manifold Absolute Pressure) sensor, which looks like this:

[image: MAP sensor]

And can be found here:

[image: Where the MAP sensor is]

Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: My '95 Bronco 351 is speed-density.  I think you have the transition year, where it's a crapshoot.  1997 went to all MAF on the 5.4 modular.  Bye Windsor, I enjoyed your ability to retain sparkplugs....

Answer (score 2):

It should be on or near the air cleaner assembly. It looks like a square thing with a 60 pin connector on it

http://www.ford-trucks.com/how-tos/a/ford-f150-f250-how-to-clean-a-faulty-mass-airflow-sensor-361730